# Rails Association Undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I would like to add "category" function.
I associated article.rb and category.rb.
However, undefined method `categories' for nil:NilClass was present.
I have no idea.If you know any solution, please tell me.

Index.html.erb

```
   <% unless @article.categories.blank? %>
         <% @articles.categories.each do |category|%>
             <%= link_to category.name,article_path(category_id:category.id)%>
         <%end%>
       <%end%>
```

article.rb

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  scope :from_category, -> (category_id)  { where(id: article_ids = ArticleCategory.where(category_id: category_id).select(:article_id))}
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  mount_uploader :image,ImageUploader
  has_many :categories, through: :article_categories
  has_many :article_categories, dependent: :destroy

  def save_categories(tags)
    current_tags = self.categoires.pluck(:name) unless self.categories.nil?
    old_tags = current_tags - tags
    new_tags = tags - current_tags

    old_tags.each do |old_name|
      self.categories.delete Category.find_by(name:old_name)
    end

    new_tags.each do |new_name|
      article_category = Category.find_or_create_by(name:new_name)
      self.categories << article_category
    end

  end

end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name,presense: true,length:{maximum:50}
  has_many :articles,through: :article_categories
  has_many :article_categories,dependent: :destroy
end
```

article_category.rb

```
class ArticleCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :category
  validates :article_id,presense:true
  validates :category_id,presense:true
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show,:edit,:update]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index,:show]
  before_action :set_article_tags_to_gon, only: [:edit]

  def index
    if params[:category_id]
      @selected_category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
      @articles= Article.from_category(params[:category_id]).page(params[:page])
    else
      @articles= Article.all.page(params[:page])
    end
    @articles = Article.page params[:page]
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
    redirect_to articles_path
    else
      render 'articles/new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @category_list = @article.categories.pluck(:name).join(",")
  end

  def update
    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to articles_path
    else
      redirect_to 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
  def article_params
    params[:article].permit(:title,:content,:image,:tag_list,:category)
  end

  def set_post
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwmvI.png)

Comment: In `articles#index` you're only setting an `@articles` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling categories on a `nil` object, in this case `@article`. Did you mean to call it on `@articles`?

If not, you will need to define `@article` in the `index` action of your controller.

Comment: It was same result, when I deleted `unless @article.categories.blank?`.